# Multiple screens - handling different screen resolutions - media queries

Tags: css, responsive-design, ionic-framework, media-queries, screen-size

Greetz ppl, i'm fairly new to the Ionic framework. As a beginner i made some crucial mistakes in my dating app which i'm still developing. Since i didn't have the responsive dev approach for my app, i had to rewrite and change a lot of CSS on mostly all of my templates. I'm coming from front-end development world and didn't work on mobile apps that much.

When i realized that my app lucks good on only few devices, I started to use media queries in order to support different screens. But i got into a problem. Been writing and adding new media queries for a lot of devices and realized that working like that i couldn't cover all of them. 
So i experimented with my own content dependent media queries and started to make breakpoints when it's suitable for me and when the content breaks.

Butt still i have a problem that a lot of devices are not covered and the design gets screwed.

How do you approach to this problem? Do you have some common methods to handle different screen sizes, density? How do you battle with dpi, ppx, px, %, max-width, max-device-width, etc...

What's the best best way to handle all of these? Is there some better solution then media queries? How to achieve that my templates look the same/ almost the same on all different devices???

I want to hear different types of possible solutions to responsive mobile apps.

UPDATE:

So as i forgot to add some code samples, i assumed that's why i didn't get larger reach of the competent developers for this problem.

Let's say that i have a view that looks like this:

[Sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6sSr.png)

Regarding the UI elements on the page, you can that some of them are not Ionic components, just some custom designed elements.

So we have header which will work good on all device screens, background img also won't be a problem.

But if we focus on main content, we have custom photo image, custom upload photo btn, step indicators, and one large btn on the bottom.

View for this page:

```
 <ion-view name="signupPhotos" class="signup-view" cache-view="true" ng-init="showCurrentStep(currentStep)"><ion-content scroll="false" class="padding background-view">
<div class="bar bar-assertive header-view">
  <a class="button back-button" ng-click="previousStep()">
    <i class="icon icon-left ion-chevron-left"></i>
  </a>
  <h1 class="title">{{'signup_account_setup_title' | translate}}</h1>
</div>`
<div class="step-icon">
  <div class="photo-icon"></div>
</div>
<div class="row form-wrapper"> 
  <div class="col">

    <form name="photos_form" class="signup-form" novalidate>
      <div class="form-fields-outer list-inset">

        <p class="text-center main-label">{{'photo_label' | translate}}</p>

        <div class="separator"></div>

        <!-- <p class="text-center subtext-label">{{'photo_sub_label' | translate}}</p>
        //dummy text, just for test, will be removed-->
        <p class="text-center subtext-label">Some test test test test test test test text text text text text
          text</p>

        <div class="user-photo" align="center">
          <img ng-src="{{regdata.imgSrc}}" ng-if="regdata.imgSrc" class="left user-signup-img" ng-click="uploadUserPhoto()"/>
          <button type="button" class="button upload-button" ng-if="!regdata.imgSrc" ng-click="uploadUserPhoto()">
            <div class="plus-icon"><i class="ion-ios-plus-outline"></i></div>
            {{ "upload_photo" | translate }}
          </button>
        </div>

      </div>
    </form>

    <div class="circles slider-pager">
      <span ng-repeat="slide in slidesData.steps">
        <span class="slider-pager-page {{slide.state}}">
          <i class="icon ion-record"></i>
        </span>
      </span>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="sign-up button button-full icon-right ion-chevron-right" ng-click="nextStep()"
            ng-disabled="photos_form.$invalid">
      {{ submitButtonText }}
    </button></div></div></ion-content></ion-view>
```

So the main content is going to look pretty good on few phone resolutions, let's say that this iPhone 6s screen is our base on which we design this view. So 6,6s, 6+ and 6s+ will be all good. Similar to them maybe Nexus 5,6 and Galaxy 5,6,7 would have the same layout.

When we get to the point of iPhone 4s,5s or maybe larger screens like Nexus 7,10 tablets or iPad Pro, iPad Mini we will have bunch of screwed elements all over the place. So then i do have to get my hands dirty with media queries in order to rearrange buttons and other elements.

The point is if i have large number of screens and large number of different screen resolutions we get to the point when the huge amount of time is lost on handling css and writing few margin, padding fixes bunch of times.

How do you deal with this, do you create few breakpoints on some width, height values or do you have some other approach on this???

Comment: Some examples of your html/css would be nice where the layout breaks. It's hard to give an overall answer to something like this without knowing your skill level and the complexity of your design etc.

Comment: i have updated my question so you can take a look at it. Tnx for the help in advance. Btw sorry for the delayed anwser